# how to identify the type of the variable declared as interface

Tags: java

consider am declaring a variable avar as

```
Set avar;
```

then ,i initialized as

```
avar= new HashSet();
```

now if i out this avar class...

```
System.out.println("class----->"+avar.getClass());
System.out.println("class name--->"+avar.getClass().getName());
System.out.println("class--super name--->"+avar.getClass().getSimpleName());
System.out.println("is interface--->"+avar.getClass().isInterface());
```

It output is :

```
class----->class java.util.HashSet
class name--->java.util.HashSet
class--super name--->HashSet
is interface--->false
```

Is it Possible to get the variable type as Set....

i mean the expected out is Set ........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the *variable* is `Set`. The type of the object that the value of the variable *refers* to is `HashSet`.

You can't get the type of the *variable* if you've only got the *value* (e.g. if this value is received by a method as a parameter).

This goes back to your earlier questions - it's still not clear to me that you've really understood my answers there...

Comment: ya i undershoot jon.. but my problem is in action am declaring as set and passing the variable to delegate ..so in delegate i had a method which has arguments as set not hashset,, so it couldn't find the method as its signature is different... ex.. set avar = new HashSet(); and passing this avar to delegate as getMethod(avar) in action... and in delegate, i had a method public void getMethod(set avar){}

Comment: @Meeran: I understand the problem that you're trying to solve, but you don't seem to understand why you *won't be able to do it*. You're not passing the *variable* to the delegate - you're passing the *value* of the variable, at which point there is *no* information about the type of the variable where that value *happened* to come from. You need to redesign.